# Find max value in a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, max

I have a vector v of objects A in a Class B where each object has a member: int level. I want to find the maximum value of the level of all the objects in the vector v. To this end I use the function:

```
int B::findMaxLevel()
{
vector<int> levels;
vector<A*>::iterator it;

for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();++it)
{
    if(find(levels.begin(), levels.end(), (*it)->getLevel())!=levels.end())
        levels.push_back((*it)->getLevel());
}

return *max_element(levels.begin(), levels.end());

}
```

However I get the error: Assertion Failed, vector iterator not deferencable. 
Should I define an int iterator additionally? Is there a better way to implement the function I want?

Comment: At what line do you get this error message?

Comment: what if `v` is empty and then `levels` becomes empty, and `max_element` returns `levels.end()` ?

Comment: What does `max_element` look like?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/

Comment: @Mohammad Ah! A good example of `using namespace std;` being bad.

Comment: Mohammad may be partially right. The vector v contains elements definitely, but the if statement seems never to be fulfilled, also weird, since each A has a level member.

Comment: Ok, the vector levels is empty because I need == in find, not !=, so as to add the value when not contained in the vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess your problem is with the last line. an empty vector will result in this error at that line.

Actually you're not filling `levels` at all. It should be `==levels.end()` instead of `!=levels.end()`

Also, take a look at the example code in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/), and try to use a user specified comparison function object instead of multiple copies.

```
    template <class ForwardIterator, class Compare>
    ForwardIterator max_element ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Compare comp );
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the exact problem you are having with the solution http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/18226/